# Count occurrences of factors across multiple columns in grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the following dataframe and want to group by the `grp` column to see how many of each column-value appears in each group.

```r
> data.frame(grp = unlist(strsplit("aabbccca", "")), col1=unlist(strsplit("ABAABBAB", "")), col2=unlist(strsplit("BBCCCCDD", "")))
  grp col1 col2
1   a    A    B
2   a    B    B
3   b    A    C
4   b    A    C
5   c    B    C
6   c    B    C
7   c    A    D
8   a    B    D
```

Desired result:

```r
  grp col1A col1B col2B col2C col2D
1   a    1    2     2     0     1
2   b    2    0     0     2     0
3   c    1    2     0     2     1
```

If I only look at the `grp` and `col1` columns, it is easy to solve this using `table()` and when there are only 2 columns, I could merge `table(df[c('grp', 'col1')])` with `table(df[c('grp', 'col2')])`. However, this gets extremely cumbersome as the number of factor columns grows, and is problematic if there are shared values between `col1` and `col2`.

Note that dplyr's count doesn't work, as it looks for unique combinations of the col1 and col2.

I've tried melting and spreading the dataframe using tidyr, without any luck

```r
> pivot_longer(df, c(col1, col2), names_to= "key", values_to = "val") %>% pivot_wider("grp", names_from = c("key", "val"), values_from = 1, values_fn = sum)
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `grp` doesn't exist.
```

I can find plenty of solutions that work for the case where I have 1 group column and 1 value column, but I can't figure out how to generalize them to more columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stack `col1` & `col2` together, count the number of each combination, and then transform the table to a wide form.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(col1:col2) %>%
  count(grp, name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(grp, names_from = c(name, value), names_sort = TRUE,
              values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  grp   col1_A col1_B col2_B col2_C col2_D
  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 a          1      2      2      0      1
2 b          2      0      0      2      0
3 c          1      2      0      2      1
```

A `base` solution (Thank **@GKi** to refine the code):

```r
table(cbind(df["grp"], col=do.call(paste0, stack(df[-1])[2:1])))

   col
grp col1A col1B col2B col2C col2D
  a     1     2     2     0     1
  b     2     0     0     2     0
  c     1     2     0     2     1
```

Comment: Two things are remarkable and very helpful to consider here. 1. the use of `id_cols` and 2. `names_sort` argument.

Comment: Maybe a more general base version: `table(cbind(df["grp"], do.call(paste0, stack(df[-1])[2:1])))`

Comment: @GKi I neglected that `cbind()` will recycle `grp` to the length of the stacked data. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `recast` from `reshape2` package:

```
reshape2::recast(df, grp~variable+value,id.var = 'grp', fun = length)

  grp col1_A col1_B col2_B col2_C col2_D
1   a      1      2      2      0      1
2   b      2      0      0      2      0
3   c      1      2      0      2      1
```

In base R you could do:

```
with(df, cbind(table(grp, paste0('col1_', col1)), table(grp, paste0('col2_', col2))))

  col1_A col1_B col2_B col2_C col2_D
a      1      2      2      0      1
b      2      0      0      2      0
c      1      2      0      2      1
```

If you have many columns consider doing:

```
do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) table(df$grp, paste(x,y, sep = '_')),
                        names(df)[-1], df[,-1]))

  col1_A col1_B col2_B col2_C col2_D
a      1      2      2      0      1
b      2      0      0      2      0
c      1      2      0      2      1
```

You can then turn this to a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with `melt` and `spread`.  Here's a tidyverse solution.  I first use `pivot_longer` to generalise to an arbitrary number of columns and then `pivot_wider` to return to the desired output format.  The order of columns in the output data frame is data dependent.  If this is an issue, simply append a `select` to the end of the pipe to obtain the desired order.  (Or use `names_sort` as in @DarrenTsai's answer.)

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("col"),
    names_to="Column",
    values_to="Value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(grp, Column, Value) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols=grp,
    values_from=N,
    names_from=c(Column, Value),
    names_sep="",
    values_fill=0
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  grp   col1A col1B col2B col2D col2C
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 a         1     2     2     1     0
2 b         2     0     0     0     2
3 c         1     2     0     1     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on a `tidyr::pivot_longer` followed by a `tidyr::pivot_wider` and using `values_fn = length`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(col1, col2)) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_c(name, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(grp, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, names_sort = T)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   grp   col1A col1B col2B col2C col2D
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         1     2     2     0     1
#> 2 b         2     0     0     2     0
#> 3 c         1     2     0     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`, we can use `dcast` + `melt` like below

```
dcast(
    melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "grp")[
        , value := paste(variable, value, sep = "_")
    ], grp ~ value
)
```

to produce

```
   grp col1_A col1_B col2_B col2_C col2_D
1:   a      1      2      2      0      1
2:   b      2      0      0      2      0
3:   c      1      2      0      2      1
```